# Is there an option to Hide/Show fields in work item(Inheritance process)?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I am new to the Inheritance process, I try to create a dynamic Work Item 
Where selection on one field value will Show/Hide another field.
In the TFS 2018 i could fill the values Using different global lists - which are not available any more.

Using Azure DevOps Server 2019.
I tried using the Rules page on the process template and couldn't find this option - this is the only documentation i found
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops

***Currently the answer is no cannot show\hide fields.***

Found a question on Microsoft site - no realy an answer but some sort of workaround...
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/545504/hide-custom-fields-in-the-inherited-model.html?childToView=604861

haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that there's no such option supported in TFS&VSTS rules now. Until now, we just support some of conditions and actions option which list on the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops).

You can raise your feature demand [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22) to promote development of richer features.

[image]

**Note**: After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously